# PostgreSQL / psql meta-command silently fails and doesn't insert rows

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've created a SQL file I run through the psql command that roughly looks like as follows:

```
truncate table my_table; 
\set content `cat /workdir/test.json` insert into my_table values ('test_row', :'content');
```

The first line is somewhat irrelevant to the problem, except for the fact it does print out "TRUNCATE TABLE", so it is reading and running the SQL file correctly, at least initially. However, the insert row is never created, the table is always empty. Yet no error message pops up.

The JSON file has a valid value (even if I pare it down to super basic `{}`). I've also tried passing the sql command directly (just to cover my bases, tried it with just one '' and same, with three it gives invalid command error):

```
psql [...] -c "\\set content `cat /workdir/test.json` insert into my_table values ('test_row', :'content')"
```

Again, no output message, no new rows created. However not using the meta-command `\set` does work. E.g.:

```
psql [...] -c "insert into my_table values ('test_row', '{}')"
```

Seems like there's something it doesn't like about the meta-command `\set`, but without any error info, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Both the script and database are running on the same VM. That is, script can call host via 'localhost' and the filesystem/filepaths should be the same, I think, should that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `psql` meta-command (something that starts with a backslash) are terminated by the end of line; you cannot have an SQL statement on the same line.

Write the `\set` in one line and the `INSERT` in another.

If you want to use the `-c` option of `psql`, use several `-c` options:

```sh
psql -c "\\set ..." -c "INSERT ..."
```